# Discrete Fourier Series of square of a signal

Tags: discrete-signals

I am having trouble in deriving a result, which asks me to find a relation between $X_{1}(k)$ and $X_{2}(k)$ where $X_{1}(k)$ are the DFS coefficients of single period of signal $x(n)$ and $X_{2}(k)$ are the DFS coefficients of two periods of the same $x(n)$. My approach is this.

$$X_{1}(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)W_{N}^{-kn}$$
and $$X_{2}(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x(n)W_{2N}^{-kn}$$
Since we know that $W_{N} = W_{2N}^{2}$. That means that, if I square $X_{2}(k)$, then I get this
$$X_{2}^{2}(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x^{2}(n)W_{2N}^{-2kn}=\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}x^{2}(n)W_{N}^{-kn}$$
Now this is where I can't move further. What should I do with the last expression. I mean what are the DFS coefficients of the square of a sequence? And also note that now we are over two periods ($2N-1$).

Comment: That squaring argument would not help you... and indeed wrong (square of $X_2[k]$ is not what you think). You better apply the steps of the solution algorithm pointed by Hilmar.

Comment: Do we really need to use $W_{2N}$ in the expression of $X_{2}(k)$. I think that would be true if it was a DFT vector but here we are talking of DFS vector, so shouldn't it be $W_{N}$ only due to the fundamental frequency? I know I am questioning my very own solution.

Comment: Hint: $W_{2N}^{kn} = e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{2N} k n } = e^{-j \frac{2\pi}{N}  \frac{k}{2} n } = W_{N}^{ \frac{k}{2}n}$

Answer (score 3):

Here is an outline (in case it's homework)

1. Use a different frequency index for $X_2(l)$
2. Split the $X_2(l)$ into two sums: from $0:N-1$ and from $N-1:2N$
3. Use the periodicity of x[n], i.e.  $x(n) = x(n+N)$
4. Substitute $m = n-N$ in the second sum
5. Recombine the two sums again
6. Stare what happens to even $l = 2k$ and odd $l = 2k+1$ terms

Comment: What I got from your algorithm is this $$ X_{2}(l) = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)W_{2N}^{-ln}$$. First of all, is it correct? If it is, I don't understand why you say put $l=2k$ and $l=2k+1$, because $l$ and $k$ are just the indexes of the DFS. We just replaced $k$ by $l$. Then why?

Comment: Your intermediate solution is wrong. There should be x[n] times the sum of two different W coefficients $ln$ and $l(n+N)$. Once you have that, pop the actual definition of $W$ and see if it simplifies further

Comment: Ok I will try and notify you.